# Prolog recursion code returning false, add in variables as input to recursive list parse

Tags: prolog

Im writing prolog to print out each element of a list, as long as a counter is > 0.

```
printLN([],_).
printLN(_,-1).
printLN([[x,y] | T], N) :-
    write(x), write(y), nl,
    N2 is N-1,
    printLN(T, N2).
```

This should print the 3 pairs.

```
printLN([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 2).
```

This should print the 3 pairs.

```
printLN([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 8).
```

This should print first pair.

```
printLN([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], 0).
```

I keep getting false though. Anyone know why this may be the case?

As well, how could i execute something like:

```
getPartialList(N) :-
    getList(LIST), printLN(LIST, N).
```

where getList returns a list of pairs like:

```
getList([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).
```

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting false though. Anyone know why this may be the case?

Two errors:
a)  write(x) should be written write(X) where X is a logical variable (in capitals).
b)  Your third clause keeps Calling recursively even if N < 0. To correct this, put a test N > 0 into this clause.

```
printLN([],_).
printLN(_, -1) :- !.
printLN([[X,Y] | T], N) :-
    N > 0,
    write(X), write(Y), nl,
    N2 is N-1,
    printLN(T, N2).
```

Comment: It would be great if you could put the `N > 0` into the code as well ;-)